# The semidirect product of $G$ with ${\rm Aut}(G)$ in the canonical way: its name and its implementation in GAP and/or Magma

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, definition, gap, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group with automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Let $A_G$ denote the semidirect product of $G$ with ${\rm Aut}(G)$ in the canonical way.

> Question 1: Is there are name for $A_G$ in the literature?
>
> Question 2: Is there a way to obtain $A_G$ in GAP (and/or Magma) for a given finite group $G$?

Comment: In Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*, it is called the *holomorph* of $G$ and denoted by $${\rm Hol}\, G.$$

Comment: There is a Magma function $\mathtt{Holomorph}(G)$.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this semidirect product be called the *holomorph*. One can create it in GAP simply as `SemidirectProduct` with no extra work:

```
gap> g:=AlternatingGroup(6);;
gap> a:=AutomorphismGroup(g);
<group with 4 generators>
gap> h:=SemidirectProduct(a,g);
<permutation group with 6 generators>
gap> Size(h);
518400
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called the *holomorph*.  For instance, for $S_n$ if $n\ne2,3,6$, we get the canonical semidirect product of $S_n$ with itself:  $S_n\rtimes S_n$.